# <af:message> ignores \n and prints it in a single line

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I am new to ADF. Please help. Pasting a snippet of my code:-
    I am unable to print a new line message with \n.

```
    <af:message id="errMessage" message="#{backingBeanScope.ta_del_entUiBean.errorMessage}" messageType="error"          
                                    visible="#{backingBeanScope.ta_del_entUiBean.error}"/>



public String getErrorMessage()
    {
        return message;
    }




message contains a String this way, say :  The following error have occurred. \n 1. Null ponter exception. \n 2. ODBC Exception \n. 3. JDBC Exception 

The output is .
The following error have occurred. 1. Null ponter exception.  2. ODBC Exception . 3. JDBC Exception

How do I make it appear as

The following error have occurred.
1. Null ponter exception.
2. ODBC Exception
3. JDBC Exception


Thanks a lot  for the help. The  Java Platform version is 1.7.0_51 and the    `Jdev` version is   12.1.3.0
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27907839/new-line-character-in-jdeveloper-string-in-java/27915419#27915419

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. But our client was using IE browser. It works well in IE browser.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the af:message or af:messages components is that they firstly get rendered on the page, and after that, the content will be attached. That's why when you insert a text containing special characters like "\n" or "\r" they will be printed as they are (actually, they are know only to the compiler who knows how to parse them, but remember, you are using an ADF faces component, not the standard output like in the case of System.out.println() ).
With this in mind, it should be clear that you have to instruct the browser how to print the content. How? Easy, just by inserting HTML tags inside your message body. In your case, the message String should be:

```
<html><body>
The following error have occurred.<br/>
1. Null ponter exception.<br/>
2. ODBC Exception<br/>
3. JDBC Exception<br/>
</body></html>
```

Or you can enclose the lines within a paragraph tag instead ( < p > ).